How to use Keras with Optuna tuning and Sklearn Pipeline
I am developing a model using Keras and use Optuna for the hyperameter tuning.
I need to use K-fold method for the development.
However, I cannot successfully run it.
Please help.
Here is the code:
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from keras.losses import MeanAbsolutePercentageError
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from category_encoders import LeaveOneOutEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold, cross_val_score

X_dev, X_val, y_dev, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)


def objective(trial, predictor):
    
    # model choice ---------       
    if predictor == 'xgb':
        params_model = {'random_state': 42,
                        'n_jobs': -1,
                        'objective': 'reg:gamma',
                        'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 30, 1000),
                        'reg_alpha': trial.suggest_float('reg_alpha', 1e-8, 100.0, log=True),
                        'reg_lambda': trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 1e-8, 100.0, log=True),
                        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 1.0, log=True),
                        'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 13)}
        model = XGBRegressor(**params_model)
        
                                
    elif (predictor == 'dnn'):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(len(X_dev.columns), activation='relu'))
        n_hidden_layers = trial.suggest_int('n_hidden_layers', 1, 20)
        for i in range(1, n_hidden_layers+1):
            num_hidden = trial.suggest_int(f'n_units_l{i}', 3, 30, log=True)
            model.add(Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        lr = trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 0.1, log=True)
        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr), loss=MeanAbsolutePercentageError())
        model = KerasRegressor(model=model, epochs=300, random_state=123, batch_size=128)
        
    # create pipeline ---------
    param_encode = {'random_state': 123,
                    'sigma': trial.suggest_float('sigma', 0.05, 0.6)}
    catencode = LeaveOneOutEncoder(**param_encode)
    pipeline = Pipeline([('catencode', catencode), ('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('model', model)])

    # model development ---------
    kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=123)
    scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_dev, y_dev, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error', cv=kf, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1) # 
    
    return scores.mean()


SAMPLER = optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=123)
N_TRIALS = 200


When I run XGB model as below, there is no issue with it
studyXGB = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize', sampler=SAMPLER)
studyXGB.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial, 'xgb'), n_trials=N_TRIALS)

But when I run DNN (which is the Keras model), I got the error as
studyDNN = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize', sampler=SAMPLER)
studyDNN.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial, 'dnn'), n_trials=N_TRIALS)

ValueError:
All the 3 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.
Below are more details about the failures:
3 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'inputs'

I also try to change the code from
model = KerasRegressor(model=model, epochs=300, random_state=123, batch_size=128)

to
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model, epochs=300, random_state=123, batch_size=128)

but I got the same error.
However, if I give up on setting the number of epoches (which is not ideal) by putting the comment in this line
# model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model, epochs=300, random_state=123, batch_size=128)

I got a different error as
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 25-44: character maps to 

However, if I just run the model with the pipeline and without Optuna, the model can successfully run.
